# Is there a way to click away from ckeditor and it saves the contents and then closes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

Im using CKEditor as my text editor. I was wondering if there is a way to click away from the editor (i.e anywhere else on the screen) which will then save the contents of it?

Comment: "ckeditor" is not a known library. Include a link to their documentations.

Comment: http://docs.ckeditor.com/

Comment: You might be looking for `$('#ckEditor').on('focusout', function() {});`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - hook up to the `blur` event for the editor, and fire off an AJAX request to your Save handler.

```
// initialise
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );

// hook up blur
editor.on('blur', function(){
    var text = this.getData();
    $.ajax('/Save', {
        method: 'POST',
        data: { 
            content: text
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(){
         ...
    }).fail(function(){
         ...
    }).always(function(){
         ...
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/sqbd2vjh/